# Can I assume static cast of sibling classes will fail to compile?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, polymorphism

Assume I have, in C++ the following pattern:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};

class C : public A {};
```

These should obviously work (typecasting to the parent):

```
A a;
B b;

a = static_cast<A>(b);
a = static_cast<A>(c);
```

These should work at compile time but may cause runtime problems:

```
b = static_cast<B>(a);
c = static_cast<C>(a);
```

Can I assume this will never pass compilation checks (assuming no constructor that converts from one class onto the other exists)?

```
b = static_cast<B>(c);
c = static_cast<C>(b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leverage proper polymorphism you should work with pointers.

Here you are just invoking `A::operator=(const A&)`. Starting from this you will have 3 default assignment operator:

```
A::operator=(const A&)
B::operator=(const B&)
C::operator=(const C&)
```

B *is-a* A and C *is-a* A so you don't need `static_cast` in your first two assignments. Using the cast will change how the assignment is done though. With a cast, the object will be sliced into a A instance through invocation of `A::A(const A&)` and then assigned through `A::operator=(const A&)` but without the cast only the latter will be called.

Your other casts will fail in any case, this because `static_cast` will look for a conversion between the two types but, for example, `static_cast<B>(a)` requires `B::B(const A&)` which is not defined.